# Table Responding very slow in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012

i having one table in sql server it conatins 6 crore (60 million) rows and has near about 80 columns the machine configration is very good and the queries on other tables respond immediately but on this table it takes very long time i have already created three indexexes on that table 
1 clustered index and 2 Non Clustered index still its response time is very slow

Comment: Please remove either the mysql tag or the sql-server-2012 tag. Also, please consider posting your table definition.

Comment: Can you post the query that you are using?